# Route Component renders multiple times when route is split into multiple files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The issue is that whenever I try to migrate my routes into another file and import them into parent file(routes.js) then whenever I tried to navigate to those migrated route the whole layout is re-rendered and if I keep migrated routes in the parent route component then the layout is rendered once as expected.

The route component where all the routes are written as below

**routes.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

import MainLayout from '../pages/layouts/MainLayout';
import Login from '../components/Login/Login';

import UserList from "../components/User/UserList";
import UserCreate from '../components/User/UserCreate';
import UserEdit from '../components/User/UserEdit';
import UserSetting from '../components/User/UserSetting';


class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Login}/>
                
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/user' component={UserList} layout={MainLayout}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/user/create' component={UserCreate} layout={MainLayout}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/user/edit/:id' component={UserEdit} layout={MainLayout}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/user/setting/:id' component={UserSetting} layout={MainLayout}/>

            </Switch>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

**UserRoutes.js**

```
import UserList from "../components/User/UserList";
import UserCreate from '../components/User/UserCreate';
import UserEdit from '../components/User/UserEdit';
import UserSetting from '../components/User/UserSetting';

const UserRoutes = [
    { 
        path        : '/user', 
        component   : UserList, 
    },
    { 
        path        : '/user/create', 
        component   : UserCreate, 
    },
    { 
        path        : '/user/edit/:id', 
        component   : UserEdit, 
    },
    { 
        path        : '/user/setting/:id', 
        component   : UserSetting, 
    },
];

export default UserRoutes;
```

Now, when I try to import this route in place of the written routes in **routes.js** component, the above mentioned issue arises.

**routes.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

import MainLayout from '../pages/layouts/MainLayout';
import Login from '../components/Login/Login';

import UserRoutes from './UserRoutes'; 


class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Login}/>
                {
                    UserRoutes.map(({ path, component }, key) => 
                        <PrivateRoute exact layout={MainLayout} path={path} component={component} key={key} />
                    )
                }

            </Switch>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Redirect, Route, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

let state_of_state = localStorage["appState"];
let Auth = {};
if (!state_of_state){
    localStorage["appState"] = JSON.stringify({user : {}});
} else {
    Auth = JSON.parse(state_of_state);
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ layout: Layout, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => {
      const newComponent = Layout ? 
           <Layout><Component {...rest} {...props} /></Layout> 
               : 
           <Component {...props} />;

      return (!_.isEmpty(Auth.user)) ? (
          newComponent
      ) : (
          <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location }}} />
      )
  }}/>
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I need some guidance where I am going wrong with this.

Comment: so you re-write the top routes.js with the bottom routes.js or you have both files

Comment: @Hogan I am re-writing the routes.js file with the bottom one.

Comment: Well this can't be the code you are actually using since the names are wrong in the file UserRoutes.js you export UserRoutes but you import UserRouteComponents in your Routes.js file

Comment: @Hogan Does that affect the functionality anyhow as I am new to react world?

Comment: Well I can't tell you what the problem is if you don't show me the code you are using -- this seems fine and it seems as if it would not do what you describe -- but since I can't see the code you are actually running I can't verify.  Probably best if you try to create a super simple example of what you are trying to do (eg just one page not 4 and get rid of all the files except 2 main and route

Comment: If you do that you will figure out your problem as you are doing it or get an answer very quickly.

Comment: @Hogan I have updated the code as per the suggestion. Now it's the same code which I am using. Please see if you figure out my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just tried code you posted with no success in reproducing your error. Here is the [code sandbox with example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-repro-62878471-qkv8z). Maybe the `PrivateRoute` is the problem? Please, include it in your question.

Comment: @macborowy -- he has it in a prior version but took it out to make the question "simpler" -- I think that showed that the problem must be in that code since it works without it.

Comment: @macborowy I have added the PrivateRoute js file also in the question. Please have a look at it and please guide me in identifying my mistake. Also, thanks for the sandbox link.